# Qt: setTextAlignment has no effect with QListWidget items

Tags: qt

```
MyItem = new QListWidgetItem(QIcon(), "Testing");
MyItem->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
this->GetListWidget()->addItem(MyItem);
```

"Testing" will always appear aligned to the left. why?

Comment: I just tried this using a minimal example and it worked as expected, I suspect there's more going on than what you've just shown.

Comment: It works correctly for me as well. (Windows 7 x64, Qt 4.7.4, MinGW)

Comment: I am on MacOS 10.7 - Qt 4.7.4 - Perhaps something with that configuration causes the problem. I'll check this under windows just to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by adding my own item delegate and doing the painting myself.